# JQuery File Upload Not Reseting

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-file-upload

I have a multiple file upload solution that is not clearing files once the "Reset" button is clicked on.  Review the [**JSFIDDLE Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/tjycea9u/19/) solution.
Here's the HTML:

```
<form id="ImageUpload" action="#">
  <div class="field" align="left">
    <h2 class="page-header">Upload your images</h3>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="file-loading">
          <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" name="Reset" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
      var files = e.target.files,
        filesLength = files.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
        var f = files[i]
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
          var file = e.target;
          $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
            "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
            "<br/><span class=\"remove\"><i class='fa fa-times'></i></span>" +
            "</span>").insertAfter("#files");
          $(".remove").click(function() {
            $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
          });
        });
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
  }
});
```

The desired outcome is to clear not only the number of selected files ("Choose Files" button) but also to clear the preview images.

[image: Current solution doesn't clear the previewed selected files]

The experience displayed below is the expected outcome, when the "Reset" button is pressed.

[image]

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: well reset has no clue about what you did to the page so you need to code something to remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a function to your reset button click.

```
$("button[name='Reset']").click(function() {
    var $input = $("#files");
    // Clear your input file value
    $input.replaceWith($input.val('').clone(true));
    // Then clear the preview of the images
    $('.pip').html('');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a funtion for the Reset button click event. Here is what you can do :

```
$(document).on('click', '[name=Reset]', function(){
   $('.pip').remove();
})
```